# Refreshing a div every 30 second with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I'm trying to automatically update a div every 30 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function refresh_handler() {
        function refresh() {
           $.get('/refresh/3', function(result) {
               $(".roek").innerHtml = result;
               console.log(result);
           });
        }
        setInterval(refresh, 3000); //every 5 minutes
    }

    $(document).ready(refresh_handler);

</script>
```

Here I'm trying to refresh the div every 30 seconds.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="roek">
        @foreach ($hours as $hour)
            @if ($hour->repeat_day === "Monday")
                <p>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <b> Day: </b> {{ $hour->repeat_day }} <a href="/deletehour/{{ $hour->id }}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="color: cyan"></span></a> <br>

                        <b> Start: </b> {{ strftime("%H:%M", strtotime($hour->starttime))}} <br>
                        <b> End: </b> {{ strftime("%H:%M", strtotime($hour->endtime))}} <br>
                    </div>
                </p>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently it's trying to refresh the Div but it doesn't update it on the refresh.
In my `web.php` I have the following:

```
Route::get('/refresh/{id}', 'RefreshController@workhoursrefresh');
```

And this is the query I'm using after the refresh:

```
//show all standard workhours per specific user
public function workhoursrefresh()
{
    $hours = Availability::FindAvailabilitys()->where([['user_id', '=', Auth::id()],
                                                       ['type', '=', 'standard']])
                                              ->orderBy('starttime', 'asc')
                                              ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function refresh_handler() {
        function refresh() {
            $.get('/refresh/3', function(result) {
                $(".roek").innerHtml = result;
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
        setInterval(refresh, 3000); //every 3 second for 30 second replace it with 30000
    }

    $(document).ready(refresh_handler);

</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging steps

1. Check the console tab of your browser's development tools for errors
2. Ensure the url `/refresh/3` is being called using the network tab of your browser's development tools
3. Ensure that the url `/refresh/3` returns the data you expect
4. Ensure at least one element with `class="roek"` is on your page

In your case, you are using jQuery - so use the `html()` method on the jQuery object as there is no innerHTML on jQuery.

Code:

```
function refresh_handler() {
    function refresh() {
         $.get('/refresh/3', function(result) {
             $(".roek").html(result);
             console.log(result);
         });
    }

    setInterval(refresh, 30000);
}

$(document).ready(refresh_handler);
```

Comment: Thanks i fixed it.